# Install mysql driver everything I turn back on my computer

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

Every time when I turn back on my computer (Not when my computer is sleeping, but after I did a soft shutdown) I need to install the MySQL driver using npm.

I install the MySQL driver using the following code

`npm install -g mysql`

---

Also, what is `-g`, I use because if I were just to use `npm install mysql`, an error would show up, and then I found that I could enter `-g`, and after I did it does install mysql and I can use it. This might the problem to why I have to install the mysql driver every time I turn on my computer. If it is, can somebody teach me how to install the mysql driver without any errors.

Comment: Why does turning off your computer remove installed programs? That's what you've got to figure out first. `-g` means "global install", that is installed for all users, system-wide.

Comment: Oh so that's what it does, thanks. I at least I think I know where to start looking and fixing

Comment: An installed NPM package is just a bunch of files on disk, so if those are going missing, or if NPM can't find them, then you've got some detective work to do. Is your system somehow booted from a clean image each time you start?

Comment: That I don't know, I am going to go check

Comment: Run `npm i mysql --verbose` and post output here.